# C#: Can I change the Assembly Version to be like this: 1.6?

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio it only seems to allow the Assembly Version to be in the format:

```
0.0.0.0
```

If I change it to:

```
1.6
```

And read it in code I get 1.6.0.0

Is there any way to change this behavior for a shorter version?

Comment: The assembly versions can be 4 numbers only. Why not ignore the last two when it's displayed? So it looks like "version 1.6".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Version` objects inherently have 4 components, but you can display a short version number in code by calling the overloaded `ToString()` method:

```
Version v = new Version(1,6,0,0);
Console.WriteLine(v.ToString(2)); // prints "1.6"
```

Comment: I added the '2': Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString(2) and now it displays exactly as I want it to.

Answer (score 8):

No. Assembly versions are always 4 numbers. When retrieving in code, you'll always get an instance of [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx), which has the numbers Major, Minor, Build, Revision.

Of course you can always set Build and Revision to 0 and only *display* the Major and Minor versions if you want. If you could describe more of your context (where you're using the version number) that would help.

Comment: Any idea how I can strip the last two off when displaying it? I have the full number loaded into a string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, simply because this is the way .Net assemblies work when it comes down to resolving the right version.